# Xcodeで"Cannot preview in this file"のメッセージが現れ、ビューを表示できなくなった

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcode12

SwiftUIで開発しています。

ある日突然XcodeにCannot preview in this fileのメッセージが現れ、ビューを表示できなくなりました。

以下の記事を見ましたが、今ひとつ言っていることがピンとこないのと、画面が違うので対処できません。

[つい忘れて調べるXcodeの設定〜スキーム追加編〜 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/kazy_dev/items/feb68f162ec3d91005d3#3build-targetbuild-scheme-buildconfiguration%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF)

どうすれば、もとの通りにプレビューを表示できるようになるのでしょうか

[image: 開発画面]

Comment: NoBuildableEntriesError: active scheme does not build this file

Select a scheme that builds a target which contains the current file, or add this file to a target that is built by the current scheme.

Comment: HumanReadableSwiftError

CreationError: noBuildExecutor

Comment: 質問は後からでも編集できるので、コメント欄ではなく本文に直接追記してみてください。